# Is it OK to recreate activity in onRestart()

Tags: android, tabactivity, activity-lifecycle

I have a complex TabActivity that contains ListViews and TextViews. Instead of messing up with manual UI update I decided to "recreate" activity (force full redraw) whenever it comes to foreground. Assume that i navigate from activity A to B. When hit back on B, activity A must be recreated. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    setupTabs();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}    

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}
```

It works, but i wonder if i am doing something wrong, maybe there is a more elegant solution. Could you please suggest best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i wonder if i am doing something wrong

You are wasting CPU time and battery life. You are making the user experience worse by forcing the activity to be always recreated from scratch.

> Could you please suggest best practice for this scenario?

The best practice would be for you to perform a "manual UI update". Divide your `setupTabs()` into two pieces, one that truly creates the tabs (called from `onCreate()`) and one that fills in the data in the widgets in the tabs (called from `onResume()`).

There may be more to it for your case, but since you elected not to explain what is so difficult about the "manual UI update", I cannot really advise you further.